# How to override SO shipping address

Tags: acumatica

I attempt to override the SO Shipping address, in the SO entry graph extension.  In this case, no additional locations are necessary.  Here is my attempt & code, but no success.

```
SOAddress soAddr = new SOAddress();
soAddr.AddressID = null;
soAddr.CustomerID = 12345;  //random customer BAccount ID
soAddr =  Base.Shipping_Address.Insert(soAddr);
soAddr.OverrideAddress = true;
soAddr.IsDefaultAddress = false;
soAddr.Address1 = "123 Main Street";
//continue remaining address fields
Base.Shipping_Address.Update(soAddr);
Base.Actions.PressSave();
```

Unfortunately the Shipping address is pulled from the Location record, and no Override happens.
I am grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SOShippingAddress address = Base.Shipping_Address.Current = Base.Shipping_Address.Select();

address.OverrideAddress = true;
address = Base.Shipping_Address.Update(address);
if (address == null)
{
    address = Base.Shipping_Address.Current;
}

address.AddressLine1 = "201 Lower Notch Rd";
address.AddressLine2 = "Office Suite 1936";
address.City = "Little Falls";
address.CountryID = "US";
address = Base.Shipping_Address.Update(address);
address.State = "NJ";
address.PostalCode = "07425";
Base.Shipping_Address.Update(address);

Base.Actions.PressSave();
```